# export to image error in amcharts run with gap in exported picture

Tags: javascript, svg, export, amcharts

We use amcharts to draw different charts. Last month we added export button without any big problem .

but in two serial charts like the picture we have problem.

in serial charts like above picture

[export to image problem error am-charts gap bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJoHh.png)

[image: export to image problem error am-charts gap bug]

When i click on export button to .png (or other extensions), freeze step run incompleted ( maybe : **svg preparing** step) the chart draw explode and export action run with problem.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the [export library](https://github.com/amcharts/export)? This sounds like a very old bug as I can't replicate this on any of the demos on the AmCharts site.

Comment: if possible for you please write this as answer because this is correct and worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an old bug as We can't replicate this on any of the demos on the AmCharts site

using the latest version of the [export library](https://github.com/amcharts/export) solved my problem.

thanks [@xorspark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106614/xorspark)

My Header file in amcharts export.js version: **1.4.36**

```
Plugin Name: amCharts Export
Description: Adds export capabilities to amCharts products
Author: Benjamin Maertz, amCharts
Version: 1.4.36
Author URI: http://www.amcharts.com/

Copyright 2016 amCharts
```

And the latest version : **1.4.61**

```
Plugin Name: amCharts Export
Description: Adds export capabilities to amCharts products
Author: Benjamin Maertz, amCharts
Version: 1.4.61
Author URI: http://www.amcharts.com/

Copyright 2016 amCharts
```